# AquireToken Callback Not Working

Tags: java, android, authentication, adal

My issue: When I pull out the adal android aquireToken calls from the MainActivity and place them in their own AuthenticationManager class, the call back doesn't seem to work. I have the following 2 methods in my AuthenticationManager class:

```
public void aquireSharePointToken(final Activity rootActivity, final Context applicationContext) {
    try {
        mAppContext = applicationContext;
        mActivity = rootActivity;
        mAuthContext= new AuthenticationContext(rootActivity, Constants.TEST_AUTHORITY, true);
        mAuthContext.acquireToken(rootActivity, Constants.TEST_SHAREPOINTRESOURCE, Constants.TEST_CLIENTID, Constants.TEST_REDIRECT, PromptBehavior.Auto, new AuthenticationCallback<AuthenticationResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(AuthenticationResult result) {
                if (result == null || result.getAccessToken() == null
                        || result.getAccessToken().isEmpty()) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Token is empty");
                } else {
                    // request is successful
                    Log.d(TAG, "Status:" + result.getStatus() + " Expired:"
                            + result.getExpiresOn().toString());
                }
                Log.d(TAG, "First Time Token: " + result.getAccessToken());
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Exception exc) {
                if (exc instanceof AuthenticationException) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Cancelled");
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Authentication error:" + exc.getMessage());
                }
            }
        });

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d(TAG, "Auth Error");
    }
}

public void aquireSharePointTokenSilently(final Activity rootActivity, final Context applicationContext) {
    try {
        mAppContext = applicationContext;
        mActivity = rootActivity;
        mAuthContext= new AuthenticationContext(rootActivity, Constants.TEST_AUTHORITY, true);
        mAuthContext.acquireTokenSilentAsync(Constants.TEST_SHAREPOINTRESOURCE, Constants.TEST_CLIENTID, getUserId(applicationContext), new AuthenticationCallback<AuthenticationResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(AuthenticationResult result) {
                Log.d(TAG,"New Token: " + result.getAccessToken());
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Exception exc) {
                Log.d(TAG, "No existing Token");
                aquireSharePointToken(rootActivity,applicationContext);
            }
        });

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d(TAG, "Auth Error");
    }
}
```

In my MainActivity class, I simply call the aquireSharePointTokenSilently method and it preforms as expected, since it's a first time log in, it prints out the "No existing token" in the Log and invokes the aquireSharePointToken method. From there, the callback never engages. For example, if the user taps the "Back" button when they are on the ADAL Log In screen that gets launched via the aquireSharePointToken method, it should Log "Cancelled".

TLDR: The aquireSharePointTokenSilently method works, the aquireSharePointToken does not work. If I don't use the AuthenticationManager class and simply do those methods from within the MainActivity, they both work flawlessly.

I have a feeling I'm missing something very basic here...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's `AuthenticationManager`? Is it [this](https://developers.arcgis.com/android/latest/api-reference/reference/com/esri/arcgisruntime/security/AuthenticationManager.html)? I suggested that you can try to follow the offical [sample code](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-android/blob/dev/sample/src/main/java/com/microsoft/aad/adal/hello/MainActivity.java) to check your code.

Comment: It's my own class I created to pull all the adal calls into 1 class that I can simply call on instead of having them inside my activities. The official sample is a very simple sample that keeps everything in the activity class. I have all that working. It's when I pull them out as stated above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you added following line in onActivityResult method of your activity. This is needed.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    <your Azure AuthenticationContext>.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```